# Symfony2: Database and Entity settings: Neither property ... nor method ...nor method ... exists in class

Tags: database, symfony, entity

I have an Symfony2 project cnnected to the database. For each table I have an entity.

Now, I am trying to connect one Entity with another using ManyToOne.

Here is the problem:

I have Two entitys: User and Workplace.

In the User Entity, I have:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Workplace")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="workplace", referencedColumnName="place")
 **/
protected $workplace;

/**
 * Set workplace
 *
 * @param integer $workplace
 */
public function setWorkplace($workplace)
{
    $this->workplace = $workplace;
}

/**
 * Get workplace
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getWorkplace()
{
    return $this->workplace;
}
```

In the Workplace Entity I have:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text")
 */
protected $place;



/**
 * Set place
 *
 * @param text $place
 */
public function setPlace($place)
{
    $this->place = $place;
}

/**
 * Get place
 *
 * @return text 
 */
public function getPlace()
{
    return $this->place;
}
```

And with that, I am getting an exception:

```
Neither property "workplace" nor method "getWorkplace()" nor method "isWorkplace()" exists in class "SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\Workplace"
```

How could this be resolved. Thank you very much.

Comment: I think you have missed setter and getter functions in each entity.

Comment: Normally not, I will edit my question with more details.

Comment: Could you send your controller code and workplace entity?

Comment: How to send this? To post in the question?

Comment: Oh, I have found the solution, When populating a form in my controller, I was using 'property' => 'workplace' instead of 'property' => 'workplace'.

Comment: Can you please answer this and I could confirm the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
->add('place','entity',  array('class'=>'yourBundle:WorkPlace',
                               'property'=>'place'))
```

in your form Type.

Answer (score 5):

@Asish AP is right, but an explanation is missing.

In the formBuilder, and if you have a relation between two entities, you have to specify the correct entity in your form type.

```
->add(
    'place',
    'entity',  
        array(
            'class'=>'yourBundle:WorkPlace', //Link your entity
            'property'=>'place' //Specify the property name in the entity
))
```

If you specify in the formBuilder, a property that doesn't exist, you will have this error:

```
Neither property "workplace" nor method "getWorkplace()" nor method "isWorkplace()" exists in class "SciForum\Version2Bundle\Entity\Workplace"
```

That was the reason of your error and the explanation of the solution.

https://creativcoders.wordpress.com/2014/06/02/sf2-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-exist-and-have-public-access-in-class/