# SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get

Tags: php, symfony

I try to do a contact form with Symfony 2.4.1 and I have the following error :

```
Neither the property "contact" nor one of the methods "getContact()", "isContact()", "hasContact()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Open\OpcBundle\Entity\Contact".
```

I understand the error itself, but I can't find any resources to solve it in SF2 forms documentation or on the web:

The controller code looks like this:

```
[..]

class OpcController extends Controller {
public function contactAction(Request $request) {      
  $contact = new Contact();

  $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(), $contact);

  $form->handleRequest($request);

  return $this->render("OpenOpcBundle:Opc:contact.html.twig",
        array("formu" => $form->createView(),
        )
  );      
}   
}
```

The Contact Entity looks like this :

```
[...] 
class Contact {
  protected $nom;
  protected $courriel;
  protected $sujet;
  protected $msg;

public function getNom() {
  return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom($nom) {
  $this->nom = $nom;
}

public function getCourriel() {
  return $this->courriel;
}

public function setCourriel($courriel) {
  $this->courriel = $courriel;
}

public function getSujet() {
  return $this->sujet;
}

public function setSujet($sujet) {
  $this->sujet = $sujet;
}

public function getMsg() {
  return $this->msg;
}

public function setMsg($msg) {
   $this->msg = $msg;
}  
}
```

And the Form class code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
  $builder->add('contact');
  ->add('nom', 'text'))
    ->add('courriel', 'email')
    ->add('sujet', 'text')
          ->add('msg', 'textarea')
    ->add('submit', 'submit');
}

public function getName() {
  return "Contact";
}

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
  $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'Open\OpcBundle\Entity\Contact', ));
}
}
```

Where is my mistake? Thanks

Comment: It's a typo issue `contact` and `Contact`

Answer (score 26):

Your error is correct and telling you that you entity `Contact` does not have the `contact` property and no related getter setter method while in your `buildForm()` you have used contact property like `$builder->add('contact');` but there is no related property exists in the entity,Define the property first in your entity

```
class Contact {
  protected $nom;
  protected $courriel;
  protected $sujet;
  protected $msg;
  protected $contact;

public function getContact() {
  return $this->contact;
}

public function setContact($contact) {
  $this->contact= $contact;
}
/* ...
remaining methods in entity 

*/
}
```

or if its a non mapped field then you have to define this field in builder as non mapped

```
$builder->add('contact','text',array('mapped'=>false));
```

By defining above you will not need to update your entity

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. I should read again the documentation about entities.

Comment: but now I have a 'contact' form field in my form and I dont' need it.

Comment: @user3049922 if you don't need the remove `add('contact','text',array('mapped'=>false));` from the form builder

Comment: Thanx, 'mapped' => false is quite helpful. +1 for that. :)