# SonataMediaBundle - Neither property nor methods exist

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle, sonata-media-bundle

I've installed Sonata Admin, Media, Classification, and few others without any problem.
I have an entity called task and I need to be able to attach some files to my tasks.So my Task entity looks like this:

```
class Task {
     //...
     /**
      * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media")
      * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_id", referencedColumnName="id")
      **/
     protected $attachment;
     //... 
}
```

and in my TaskAdmin.php I have

```
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper
        //...
        ->add('attachment', 'sonata_media_type', array(
            'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
            'context'  => 'default'
        ));
}
```

And here is the config.yml settings for MediaBUndle:

```
sonata_media:

default_context: default
db_driver: doctrine_orm # or doctrine_mongodb, doctrine_phpcr
contexts:
    default:  # the default context is mandatory
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.dailymotion
            - sonata.media.provider.youtube
            - sonata.media.provider.image
            - sonata.media.provider.file
        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
cdn:
    server:
        path: /uploads/media # http://media.sonata-project.org/
filesystem:
    local:
        directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
        create:     false
```

Now when I try to create a new task (http://myweb.dev/app_dev.php/admin/core/task/create)I get the following error:

```
Neither the property "attachment" nor one of the methods "getAttachment()", "attachment()", "isAttachment()", "hasAttachment()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "CoreBundle\Entity\Task".
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

---

### Similar Problem

[SonataUserBundle - Neither property nor methods exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29983814/sonatauserbundle-neither-property-nor-methods-exist)

Comment: What exactly is your question? It is unclear what your issue is.

Comment: I got an error when I visit the link that I mention...Please have a look at the error message and let me know if you can help me

Comment: @cute.S post your task entity with `attachment` getter and setters

Comment: you forgot the getters and setters for $attachment

Comment: Thanks pcm.... it did the trick :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your task entity must have an attachment field with getters and setters. For example:

```
protected $attachment;

public function getAttachment()
{
    return $this->attachment;
}
```

Comment: Thank you both. Yes you are right... I forgot the setter/getter methods

Comment: Guys would you please read from "Similar Problem" title onward and see if you can help me with that one as well.