# SonataUserBundle - Neither property nor methods exist

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I have installed Sonata User, Admin, Media and a few other bundles successfully. I want to add profile pic to user entity so I've added a $profilePic property to it (with setter and getter) as follow:

```
    /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Entity\Media",cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="profilePic_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 **/
protected $profilePic;

public function getProfilePic()
{
    return $this->profilePic;
}

public function setProfilePic($profilePic)
{
    $this->profilePic = $profilePic;
}
```

And I have a form for editing profile like this:

```
    class ProfileType extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                //...
                ->add('profilePic', 'sonata_media_type', array(
                'provider' => 'sonata.media.provider.image',
                'context'  => 'default'
                ));
        }
        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User', 
                'intention'  => 'profile',
                'label' => 'Edit Profile'
            ));
        }
    }
```

I don't need an Admin class for it because each user should be able to edit his profile from frontend.
Now when I try to edit profile for a user (http://myweb.dev/app_dev.php/profile/edit-profile) I get following error:

```
Neither the property "profilePic" nor one of the methods "getProfilePic()", 
"profilePic()", "isProfilePic()", "hasProfilePic()", "__get()" exist and have 
public access in class "Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User".
```

Can you help me realize what I'm doing wrong please?
Thank you.

p.s.
1. I need to mention my User entity extends from SonataUserBundle.
2. I though if I modify my ProfilrType as follow it might fix the problem:

```
class ProfileType extends AbstractType
    {
    //...
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
         {
             $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                 'data_class' => 'CoreBundle\Entity\User', //Now it points to my original user entity
                 //...
             ));
         }
    }
```

But I get following error which I don't understand what it means:

```
    The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class CoreBundle\Entity\User, 
    but is an instance of class Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User. 
    You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a 
    view transformer that transforms an instance of class 
    Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User to an instance of CoreBundle\Entity\User.
```

Your help is very much appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)