# Neither the property xxx exist and have public access in class blabla... but they do

Tags: symfony

i hope its a silly problem but i can't see it. I'm working on a Symfony 2 project (version 2.7) and i have this Exception :

> Neither the property "contracts" nor one of the methods "addContract()"/"removeContract()", "setContracts()", "contracts()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\User\User"

I understand the exception but addContract() exists and is public, so do the property contracts in my User class. I got this exception when i submit a form. (In this form, i include the contracts form. The problem might be here)

My UserClass with contracts property

```
/**
 * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
private $contracts;

/**
 * Add contracts
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Work\Contract $contracts
 * @return User
 */
public function addContract(Contract $contracts)
{
    $this->contracts[] = $contracts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove contracts
 *
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Work\Contract $contracts
 */
public function removeContract(Contract $contracts)
{
    $this->contracts->removeElement($contracts);
}

/**
 * Get contracts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getContracts()
{
    return $this->contracts;
}
```

My UserType form

```
class UserType extends BaseType {
/**
 * Constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct('AppBundle\Entity\User\User');
}

/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array                $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
        ->add('number', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'form.number',
        ))
        ->add('seniority', 'date', array(
            'label' => 'form.seniority',
            'widget' => 'single_text',
            'input'  => 'datetime',
            'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
        ))
        ->add('comment', 'textarea', array(
            'label' => 'form.comment',
            'required' => false,
        ))
        ->add('contracts', new ContractType());
}
```

As you can see, i add my Contract Form to my builder, and its render great. I got the exception when i submit it.

Ah, and i use Yaml mapping. The relation between User and Contract is a OneToMany - ManyToOne. One user can have many contracts.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should build your form like this (as of `contracts` is an ArrayCollection type):

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);
    $builder
        ....
        ->add('contracts', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ContractType(),
            'by_reference' => false,
            ...
        ));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that is exaclty what i did while waiting for answer^^ Actually doind like that is logical due to the OneToMany relation.