# Neither the property nor one of the methods exist and have public access in class in custom FieldType

Tags: php, symfony, custom-field-type

I added an custom FieldTypeExtension in my symfony project. I want to extend the SubmitType, the SubmitTypeExtension.php looks like:

```
class SubmitTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return SubmitType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('button_image','button_color'));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if (isset($options['button_image'])) {
            $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();

            $buttonImage = null;
            if (null !== $parentData) {
                $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
                $buttonImage = $accessor->getValue($parentData, $options['button_image']);
            }

            $view->vars['button_image'] = $buttonImage;
        }
        if (isset($options['button_color'])) {
            $parentData = $form->getParent()->getData();

            $buttonColor = null;
            if (null !== $parentData) {
                $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
                $buttonColor = $accessor->getValue($parentData, $options['button_color']);
            }

            $view->vars['button_color'] = $buttonColor;
        }
    }
}
```

I call the field type in an custom Type:

```
class VereinType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array(
                'label' => 'Speichern',
                'button_image' => 'check',
                'button_color' => 'rgba(13, 135, 13, 1)'
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'TeilnehmerBundle\Entity\Verein',
        ));
    }
}
```

I need this to customize my submitType with a glyphicon.

```
{% extends 'bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig' %}

{%- block submit_widget -%}
    {% set attr = attr|merge({class: (attr.class|default('btn-default') ~ ' btn btn-lg btn-sm')|trim}) %}
    {%- if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
            '%name%': name,
            '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <button type="{{ type|default('submit') }}" {{ block('button_attributes') }}><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{ button_image }}" aria-hidden="true" style="color: {{ button_color }};"></span><b>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</b></button>
{%- endblock submit_widget -%}
```

In the services.yml I've added the service

```
  app.submit_type_extension:
    class: TeilnehmerBundle\Form\Extension\SubmitTypeExtension
    tags:
      - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType }
```

But now I get the following error

```
Neither the property "check" nor one of the methods "getCheck()", "check()", "isCheck()", "hasCheck()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "TeilnehmerBundle\Entity\Verein".
```

The problem is, I can't have any property like the two I've added because I only use them to customize my buttons. 
Can anyone help me?

Comment: try to add `mapped => false` in your form builder? I think that if these parameters are just for view rendering you could achieve this easier by just adding your values under `attr` in the form builder and accessing them in the template widget (without the extension).

Comment: Yeah, but this is not a attribute of the button-tag. I have to put something between <button> ... </button>, with the `attr` in the form builder I could only pass something in the button tag itself. When I add the content in `label`, the HTML-Code is printed out and is not interpreted correctly.

Comment: mapped is not a valid option for SubmitType :-(

Comment: ah, if it was label related you can use the `label_attr` array to pass any additional parameters for the rendering (?)
but it seems that you got the extension way working as well :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SF2 form : error Neither the property ... nor one of the methods "get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22593677/sf2-form-error-neither-the-property-nor-one-of-the-methods-get)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified following in my SubmitTypeExtension:

```
class SubmitTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    /**
     * Returns the name of the type being extended.
     *
     * @return string The name of the type being extended
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return SubmitType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefined(array('button_image','button_color'));
    }

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        if(isset($options['button_image']))
            $view->vars['button_image'] = $options['button_image'];
        else
            $view->vars['button_image'] = NULL;

        if(isset($options['button_color']))
            $view->vars['button_color'] = $options['button_color'];
        else
            $view->vars['button_color'] = NULL;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'button_image' => null,
            'button_color' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

Now all works fine :)